# Hide previous html section within jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

The code given below is used to check whether the provided answer is right or not, the answer can be selected using radio button. When next button is clicked then 1st question must be hided and next question should be displayed. I need another button "previous" which should display previous question if it is clicked and the current question must be hided.

```
<div id="question_2" class='questions'>
<h2 id="question_2">2.Questions</h2>
<div class='align'>
<input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_2' name='2'>
<label id='ans1_2' for='1'>Answer 1</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2_2' name='2'>
<label id='ans2_2' for='1'>Answer 2</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3_2' name='2'>
<label id='ans3_2' for='1'>Answer 3</label>
<br/>
<input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4_2' name='2'>
<label id='ans4_2' for='1'>Answer 4</label>
<input type="radio" checked='checked' value="5" style='display:none' id='radio4_2' name='2'>
</div>
<br/>
<input type="button" id='next2' value='Next' name='question' class='button'/>
<input type="button" id="previous" value="Previous" name="question" class="button"/>
</div>  

      $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#demo1').stopwatch().stopwatch('start');
            var steps = $('form').find(".questions");
            var count = steps.size();
            steps.each(function(i){
                hider=i+2;
                if (i == 0) {   
                    $("#question_" + hider).hide();
                    createNextButton(i);
                }
                else if(count==i+1){
                    var step=i + 1;
                    //$("#next"+step).attr('type','submit');
                    $("#next"+step).on('click',function(){

                       submit();

                    });
                }
                else{
                    $("#question_" + hider).hide();
                    createNextButton(i);
                }

            });
            function submit(){
                 $.ajax({
                                type: "POST",
                                url: "ajax.php",
                                data: $('form').serialize(),
                                success: function(msg) {
                                  $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
                                  $('#result').show();
                                  $('#result').append(msg);
                                }
                 });

            }
            function createNextButton(i){
                var step = i + 1;
                var step1 = i + 2;
                $('#next'+step).on('click',function(){
                    $("#question_" + step).hide();
                    $("#question_" + step1).show();
                });
            }
            setTimeout(function() {
                  submit();
            }, 50000);
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check this:

I used the currentStep input to see easily on which question we are.

If you like on the next or previous button you can check if you're on the first or in the last question to hide or show next and previous buttons.

When you're on the last question and you click on next it will raise the submit. I changed it with an alert to see it.

https://jsfiddle.net/netvicious/7hzgdzcp/

```
<input type='text' id='currentStep' value='1'>

<div id="question_1" class='questions'>
  <h2>Question 1</h2>
  <div class='align'>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_1' name='1' />
    <label id='ans1_1' for='1'>Answer 1</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2_1' name='1' />
    <label id='ans2_1' for='1'>Answer 2</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3_1' name='1' />
    <label id='ans3_1' for='1'>Answer 3</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4_1' name='1' />
    <label id='ans4_1' for='1'>Answer 4</label>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="question_2" class='questions'>
  <h2>Question 2</h2>
  <div class='align'>
    <input type="radio" value="1" id='radio1_2' name='2' />
    <label id='ans1_2' for='2'>Answer 1</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="2" id='radio2_2' name='2' />
    <label id='ans2_2' for='2'>Answer 2</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="3" id='radio3_2' name='2' />
    <label id='ans3_2' for='2'>Answer 3</label>
    <br/>
    <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio4_2' name='2' />
    <label id='ans4_2' for='2'>Answer 4</label>
  </div>
</div>

<br/>
<input type="button" id='next' value='Next' name='question' class='button' />
<input type="button" id="previous" value="Previous" name="question" class="button" />
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
      steps = $('.questions').size();
      $('.questions').hide();
      $("#question_1").show();

      $('#next').on('click', function() {
          $('.questions').hide();
          elem = parseInt(parseInt($('#currentStep').val()) + 1);
          if (elem == steps + 1) {
            submit(); // If the current one was the last submit 
          } else {
            $("#question_" + elem).show();
            $('#currentStep').val(elem);
          }
         });

        $('#previous').on('click', function() {
          elem = parseInt(parseInt($('#currentStep').val()) - 1);
          if (elem == 0) return; // It was the first question so no previous one 
          $('.questions').hide();
          $("#question_" + elem).show();
          $('#currentStep').val(elem);
        });

        function submit() {
            alert('posting');
          exit;

          $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax.php",
            data: $('form').serialize(),
            success: function(msg) {
              $("#quiz_form,#demo1").addClass("hide");
              $('#result').show();
              $('#result').append(msg);
            }
          });

        }

      });
```